# Shorter and less verbose condition when using Html.DisplayFor()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

There is the following razor code.

```
<p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Price)</p>
```

Now, I need to display text "Free" when the price is 0. So I did the following.

```
<p>
  @(item.Price == 0 ? "Free" : string.Format("{0:$0.00}", item.Price))
</p>
```

It looks very verbose. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you use Display templates?

Comment: If your using view model, you could make the property nullable and use the `NullDisplayText` property of `[DisplayFormat]` attribute

Comment: @dc7a9163d9, Does it work? Does it generate the html for the item?

Comment: @T.Rahgooy Right, it doesn't work.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm trying not to change the view model.

Comment: `@{}` does not render anything, use `@()` to render the content.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi How to use Display template in DisplayFor?

Comment: @T.Rahgooy Updated the question. However, the "Free" is not displayed when it's 0. (Updated again now it works)

Comment: @dc7a9163d9, `Html.DisplayText()` used to get a property value in the model, not displaying constant text

Comment: @T.Rahgooy, yes, I figured it out so I just render the raw text. It should be safe because the `string.Format("{0:$0.00}", ...) needn't to be encoded to html.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 _"I'm trying not to change the view model"_? is a rather strange statement - a view model is a model representing what you want to display in the view :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I didn't create another another viewmodel for the view/page (it's a very simple page and seem not worth the effort). So the page uses the model directly.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 write your own html extension?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DisplayTemplates](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm), So first create your template in (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Price.cshtml`):

```
@model float
<div>
    @(Math.Abs(Model) < 1 ? "Free" : string.Format("{0:$0.00}", Model))
</div>
```

Then use this way:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(p => item.Price, "Price")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model try `[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "FREE")]`

Comment: I don't want to change the model because I want to display 0 (the field cannot be null) as 0 at some other places.

Answer (score 0):

you can write ExtensionMethods for htmlHelper to check your situation and run proper DisplayFor()